# i want to loop through all items in the dataGrid and compare with a particular one

Tags: vb.net, scripting, flex3, qtp

I want to loop through all the items in the datagrid and compare them with a particular item(unique) present in the datagrid itself, and if it is not equal that unique item (**"My Pipeline"** is the name of that particular item) with which i want to compare rest of the items with then delete that item and move on to the next item and compare again.

```
intRowCount = Browser("Browser").appliaction("abc").FlexTitleWindow("Views").AdvancedDataGrid(dgView).GetItemsCount
For i=0 to intRowCount
 Browser("Browser").appliaction("abc").FlexTitleWindow("Views").AdvancedDataGrid(dgView).SelectIndex i
If Browser("Browser").appliaction("abc").FlexTitleWindow("Views").AdvancedDataGrid(dgView).GetROProperty("SelectedItem") <> Browser("Browser").appliaction("abc").FlexTitleWindow("Views").AdvancedDataGrid(dgView).GetROProperty("My Pipeline") Then
Browser("Browser").appliaction("abc").FlexTitleWindow("Views").FlexButton("Delete View").Click
```

I want to loop through until all other views are deleted except my Default view (MY Pipeline).

Please suggest some logic.

Comment: First, I'd recommend using the `With` clause; as in `With Browser("Browser").appliaction("abc").FlexTitleWindow("Views").AdvancedDataGrid(dgView)`  Then you can just do a .GetItemsCount or .SelectedIndex.  Cleans up the code dramatically.

Comment: Secondly, you probably need to loop backwards.  If you loop forwards, deleting stuff, it could cause some problems (since the list is being modified).  Looping backwards and deleting solves problems with your list deleting items before the currently examined item (which throws an exception) or running off the end of the list (which throws an exception).  So, go `For i = .SelectedIndex-1 To 0`

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that i have implemented to download the data from DataGrid to CSV file.
This may be useful to you.

Remember dgSessionReport is my Datagrid, first_name and last_name is my datafield name.

First I am creating a String that contains csv data and then i am writing that into file having extension .csv

You need to do is in the 2nd for loop you need to write

```
if(searchString == dataProvider[i].first_name)
{
    dataProvider[i].first_name = "";
}
```

Here is my code

```
public function btnDownload_click():void
{
var csvData:String = "";

var columns:Array = dgSessionReport.columns;
var dataProvider:Object = dgSessionReport.dataProvider;

for(var i:int=0;i<columns.length;i++)
{
    if(i != columns.length - 1)
    {
        csvData += columns[i].headerText + ",";
    }
    else
    {
        csvData += columns[i].headerText;
    }
}
csvData += "\n";

for(var i:int=0;i<dataProvider.length;i++)
{
    csvData += dataProvider[i].first_name + ",";
    csvData += dataProvider[i].last_name;

    csvData += "\n";
}

var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileRef.save(csvData,"Session Report.csv");
```

}